# Volley error with own server

Tags: android, android-volley, arrays, json

i am trying to use this brilliant [tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-facebook-like-custom-listview-feed-using-volley/) to get volley working with my own server, i have managed to get it working with their links etc..., but now i want to do it with my own, however the fragment is not displaying anything and i have noticed in the logcat the error,

```
D/Volley﹕ [1] 2.onErrorResponse: NoticesFragment
```

Which is the fragment it should display in, here is the feed_array.json

```
{
"feed": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "National Geographic Channel",
        "image": "",
        "status": "\"Science is a beautiful and emotional human endeavor,\" says Brannon Braga, executive producer and director. \"And Cosmos is all about making science an experience.\"",
        "profilePic": "",
        "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
        "url": null
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "TIME",
        "image": "",
        "status": "30 years of Cirque du Soleil's best photos",
        "profilePic": "",
        "timeStamp": "1403375851930",
        "url": "http://ti.me/1qW8MLB"
    }
]
```

}

And here is the relevant code

```
  public class NoticesFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = NoticesFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private ListView listView;
    private FeedListAdapterNotices listAdapter;
    private List<FeedItem> feedItems;
    private String URL_FEED = "http://127.0.0.1:81/wst/feed_array.json";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_notices, container, false);
        listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
        getList();
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        getList();
    }

    private void parseJsonFeed(JSONObject response) {
        try {
            JSONArray feedArray = response.getJSONArray("feed");

            for (int i = 0; i < feedArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject feedObj = (JSONObject) feedArray.get(i);

                FeedItem item = new FeedItem();
                item.setId(feedObj.getInt("id"));
                item.setName(feedObj.getString("name"));

                // Image might be null sometimes
                String image = feedObj.isNull("image") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("image");
                item.setImge(image);
                item.setStatus(feedObj.getString("status"));
                item.setProfilePic(feedObj.getString("profilePic"));
                item.setTimeStamp(feedObj.getString("timeStamp"));

                // url might be null sometimes
                String feedUrl = feedObj.isNull("url") ? null : feedObj
                        .getString("url");
                item.setUrl(feedUrl);

                feedItems.add(item);
            }

            // notify data changes to list adapater
            listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getList(){



        feedItems = new ArrayList<FeedItem>();

        listAdapter = new FeedListAdapterNotices(this, feedItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);



        // We first check for cached request
        Cache cache = AppController.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: did your string that your server pass to volley had any line break?

Comment: Im not sure, but i believe i found the answer to the problem, i code the app on my laptop, which also runs the xampp, however i test it on a seperate device, so when i set the url to 127.0.0.1 (localhost), it couldnt connect, silly mistake, but i guess its all learning.

Comment: first of you are doing it wrongly. you must first see whats you computer ip is and then also turn off your firewall if you are using windows you must allow it to listen to port 80. after that you can connect to your computer and can check my answer:-)